# NginX cuts out stream to a server at "random"

Tags: nginx

I've setup my personal restreaming server with NGINX (1.7.12.1 Lizard with RTMP module, but tried a few others and result the same), but at random times random intervals this thing keeps CUTTING the stream that goes out to youtube's server, while on twitch it's always fine.

Took NginX from here : http://nginx-win.ecsds.eu/download/
Then just changed the NginX conf file by adding this at the end :

```
rtmp { 
        server {
                listen 1935;
                chunk_size 4096;

                application live {
                        live on;
                        record off;

                         push rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/YT-KEY;
                         push rtmp://live-arn.twitch.tv/app/TW-KEY;
                }
        }
}
```

Tried to re-arrange the "push" commands (swapping which one gets pushed 1st) but no luck.

Is there a way to debug..or find out WHY does it cut out connection and find out IF it's even NginX that's at fault here?

Note : did try using NginX error/warning logs, they don't register the "cut-outs".

Note 2 : NginX resumes stream after random intervals too for random periods of time.

Note 3 : After hosting NginX on a separate PC (the same local network) issue still persists

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue stemmed from Youtube (which was the cause of this post) and solution is CHUNK SIZE. Once I put it to lowest : 1024 the issues stopped appearing. At the moment at least!